# does a project inherit dependencyManagement from dependency's parent

Tags: maven, maven-3

project A depends on project B.

project B has parent C.

C defines dependencyManagement section.

Does A get dependencyManagement from C? Or does C's dependencyManagment section have no impact on project A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not inherit dependencyManagement this way. But you can [import](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Importing_Dependencies)
dependencyManagement of C. Normally this would be done in the parent of A. (But you can do it in A's pom.xml also)

Sample:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
           <groupId>com.c.group</groupId>
           <artifactId>c</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <scope>import</scope>
           <type>pom</type>
          </dependency>   
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
```

This way dependency management of C will be imported.

Comment: It could be even more interesting: if project B version is inherited from a BOM imported by project A and that BOM has a parent with `dependencyManagement` that affect A's test dependency D you'll have D's version from that BOM's parent.

Comment: For example https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3934?focusedCommentId=17636242&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-17636242